# How to send an input (letter y) after the command requests me to

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, windows-11, userscripts

I am trying to do chkdsk C: /f /r /x
After I do this command, It requests me to press y to accept checking my disk after restarting my pc.
How can I automate this for my .bat file? I mean, after the chkdsk command requests me to enter y to send y input to the terminal.
In other words, I want the batch file command to press y when chkdsk requests me to press y.
[image: chkdsk is requesting to press y]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
echo y | chkdsk C: /f /r /x
```

The pipe ( | ) feeds the output from the echo command as input to chkdsk.
Please note that that chkdsk actually wants a **y** AND **a linefeed/return**, but echo will add the linefeed automatically.

Comment: it did not work:
https://imgur.com/a/HJQErni

Comment: It DID work. It says the disk will be checked on next boot, which is the result of accepting the Y. That is totally expected to happen. You can't check and repair  with a dismount (you specified /x) the system drive without rebooting because dismounting it would crash the OS. So it needs to reboot in a special mode, dismount and check/repair, and do another reboot for a normal startup (Report on the results of the chkdsk will be written to EventLog and can be read there after the computer is back online.

Comment: thanks now I understood how It works. It does not show the echo on terminal.

Comment: How can I show the echo on terminal?

Comment: @EyalCohen I can't image why you would want that in this case. But you can't in a command-prompt pipe construct. The output of echo that normally goes to the screen, goes into the pipe that connects it to the input of chkdsk. So it never appears on-screen. In Linux/Unix like shells you can use "tee" to duplicate the output of a command into 2 streams. Then you can pipe/redirect one of them to another command and the other to the display (or a log-file). But CommandPrompt doesn't have that feature.